# Create a Config Variable

Tags: postgresql

I have been searching a way to create/Edit a config variable and using it in a stored procedure in `postgresql`. I hope that this will be a simple one to accomplish but i did not find any ways to achieve this. Can any body know the exact syntax for that?

DBMS: `Postgresql` 9.0.3

Comment: For what will this variable be used?

Comment: @DanBracuk it will act like a global variable for all my store procedures.

Answer (score 2):

`plpgsql` functions don't have global variables, nor SQL.

You may see if [`custom_variable_classes`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-custom.html) fits your needs.

With PostgreSQL versions before 9.2, it is necessary to declare the variable class in `postgresql.conf` which is sometimes a problem with regard to deployment and permissions.

With 9.2 and above, instantiation happens on the fly.

Otherwise you can use a global table with name/value pairs to store the variables.